# method getValueAt() of my database app returns "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number". Why?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I have accepted various types of data inputs (integer, double, string and date) to my embedded JDBC database via (*JTextLabels* EDIT: JTextFields) using ResultSet and i am displaying results in a swing JTable using my custom AbstractTableModel. The following are snippets from my codes where am thinking the problem might lie, but i'm not sure;

```
public void connectToDB()
    {
        try
        {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD);
            statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            connectedToDB = true;
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlEx)
        {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

//Overrides AbstractTableModel's getValueAt() method
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) throws IllegalStateException
    {
        connectToDB();
        if (connectedToDB == false)
            throw new IllegalStateException ("Not Connected To database");
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if ( resultSet.next() == true )
                {
                    resultSet.absolute( row + 1 );
                    return resultSet.getObject( column + 1 );
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException sqlEx)
            {
                sqlEx.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "";// returns an empty string Object in case an error occurs above
    }
```

It looks as if somwhere around the getValueAt() method, it generates the following exception, but even the stacktrace doesnt point me to any part of my code;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:487)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:140)
    at javax.swing.JTable$DoubleRenderer.setValue(JTable.java:5315)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(DefaultTableCellRenderer.java:223)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5683)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getToolTipText(JTable.java:3328)
............ 
*Others ommitted 4 brevity*
............
```

I dont know why.

Comment: What is a `JTextLabel`?  I don't see it in the J2SE [class listing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/allclasses-frame.html) for Java 7.

Comment: Lolz... cldnt help but comment after what?(One Year?) lmao! Nasty typing mistake in a hurry...  I actually meant JTextField, myBad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace indicates the problem is situated in the renderer of the table. The `JTable` has decided it will use the `DoubleRenderer` for that particular value, and that value can not be parsed to a `Double`. I would suggest to check your [`TableModel#getColumnClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getColumnClass%28int%29) implementation and see whether it returns `Double.class` for a column which actually does not contain `Double`s since that is the method which is used to determine which renderer to use.

This can be seen in the [source code](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/JTable-source.html) for `JTable`, more specifically in the source of the `getRenderer` method. See below for the relevant part (line 3454 in the source code I linked to)

```
 TableCellRenderer renderer = null;
 if (columnModel.getColumnCount() > 0)
   renderer = columnModel.getColumn(column).getCellRenderer();
 if (renderer == null)
   {
     int mcolumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
     renderer = getDefaultRenderer(dataModel.getColumnClass(mcolumn));
   }
 return renderer;
```

Comment: @ Robin - Thanks. I think you're right. & even though i found a walk-around alternative earlier, I'll still follow your suggestion to see if it'll give me a better implementation. I'll let you know soon as there's an improvement. You've been really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you are calling `java.text.DecimalFormat.format()` look at what is being passed in there. Whatever it is isn't a something that the`DecimalFormat` class can handle.

If you aren't calling that class and method directly, then a **step debugger** is your best friend. Set a `break point` on `DecimalFormat.format()` and use the **step debugger** to see what is being passed in that is the illegal argument.

Comment: @ Robin - Thanks. I think you're right. & even though i found a walk-around alternative earlier, I'll still follow your suggestion to see if it'll give me a better implementation. I'll let you know soon as there's an improvement. You've been really helpful.

Comment: Yes. Truly i aint calling the class method directly. Robin gave me some suggestions which i intend to use along with this step debugger thingy. Hopefully it'll work. Thanks for the tip!